# Layout that has background image, what is the best practice to handle that for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have attached the image in which i want to make the layout that is pointed with arrow.

What i have done. I assigned a background-image(Image2) to relative layout and its width height is wrap content and then i have set text( 400 OFF ) and logo (RW Ritu Wera) on it. now problem is that if device width is large, then relative layout width, which is equal to the width-height of Image2, become less in width and ui looks not properly.

what is best practice to handle this kind of ui.

Image2
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to design your image for different screen sizes

```
res/drawable-mdpi      
res/drawable-hdpi       
res/drawable-xhdpi      
res/drawable-xxhdpi
```

and this tool could help you with it

[Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Comment: I have done this. but problem still exists according to device width

Answer (score 1):

Create three different `Layouts Folder` in your `res` folder for all devices and use the dimensions accordingly.

**Generic Layout Folders**

```
res/layout-small
res/layout-normal
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
```

After you are done with making your Normal/Medium Layouts follow these steps:

1. Convert the Normal Dimensions for other Screen Sizes.
2. Copy your Normal Layout xml files in to other Folders.
3. Change the suffix of the dimensions used according to the folder that you are in
4. Resize the Image Resources in your drawable folder (Width and Height - Same technique as we used for converting the dimens) and put them in their respective drawable folder (drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xdpi and so on).
5. Then your Layouts should work on every device with correct positioning.

**For converting Values**

```
0.75 - ldpi  (small)   //mdpi dimens *0.75
1.0  - mdpi  (normal)  //First create these dimensions
1.5  - hdpi  (large)   //mdpi dimens *1.5
2.0  - xhdpi (xLarge)  //mdpi dimens *2.0
```

**For Example**

```
android:layout_width="66dip" //in normal
android:layout_width="100dip"//in large 66*1.5=100(approx)
android:layout_width="52dip" //in small 66*0.75=52(approx)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can you share your xml file